# $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$ implies $v(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\frac{f(y)}{|x-y|}dy\in W^{2,2}$?

Tags: sobolev-spaces, convolution, regularization, potential-theory

Let $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$ be a function with compact support and define $v:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}$ by $$v(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\frac{f(y)}{|x-y|}dy$$

Is true that $v\in W^{2,2}(\mathbb{R}^3)$ and $$\|v\|_{2,2}\leq C\|f\|_2$$

for some positive constant $C$?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\mathrm{supp}(f)\subset B(0,R) \subset\subset \Omega$ for some open and bounded $\Omega$ such that $\mathrm{dist}(B,\partial\Omega) \geq h>0$, then 
$$v(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\Gamma(x-y)f(y)dy = \int_{\Omega}\Gamma(x-y)f(y)dy.$$
By $L^p$-estimate of Poisson equation (Calderon-Zygmund, GT theorem 9.9, $1<p<\infty$):
$$
\|D^2 v\|_{L^p(\Omega)} \leq C\|f\|_{L^p(\Omega)}.
$$
Moreover, the trace of $v$ is zero on $\partial \Omega$ (you might need to prove this using a mollifier sequence argument for $f$), similar argument applies for $\nabla v$ for $$\nabla v(x) = \int_{\Omega}\nabla_x\Gamma(x-y)f(y)dy.$$

Now by [Friedrichs' inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedrichs%27_inequality):
$$
\|v\|_{L^p(\Omega)}\leq C\|\nabla v\|_{L^p(\Omega)}\leq C\|D^2 v\|_{L^p(\Omega)},
$$
which implies $v\in W^{2,p}(\Omega)$, then extending $v$ to $ W^{2,p}(\mathbb{R}^3)$ will finish the job.

Comment: Interesting. Now it seems to me that if I take $f\in H^{-1}(\mathbb{R})^3$ with support compact, then $\Gamma\star f\in W^{1,p}$. What do you think? The question is related to this one: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/430939/why-gamma-star-f-in-w1-p-mathbbrn

Comment: @Tomás I am still pondering about all the big pictures of the questions you raised in past few days.

Comment: Well at least I am not alone. Those problems are making me tired. I just found a good book of Ladyzhenskaia: http://books.google.com.br/books/about/The_mathematical_theory_of_viscous_incom.html?id=qVXvAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y It seems that the answer is there although I could not decipher it yet. If you have access to this book take a look in pages 33 and 66.

Comment: @Tomás GT's proof on the regularity estimate or Calderon-Zygmund's original proof on the inequality relies heavily on the integrability of $f$, so does the Hölder estimate the proof needs. For $H^{-1}$ or $W^{-k,p}$ I am curious why that author thought that the regularity lifting was trivial w/o citing any reference.

Comment: I am almost sending him an e-mail asking... Anyway, do you think I can believe it, or there is any chance for it to be wrong. The paper is very cited.

Comment: Sorry @Shuhao, but I can't see how you reach the inequality $\|v\|_{1,p}\leq C\|D^2 v\|_p$.  Do you applied Friedrichs' inequality in $\nabla v$?

Comment: Sorry again, but are you sure that $v(x)=0$ on $\partial \Omega)$? For example. if $f=1$ in $\Omega$, then $v(x)>0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: @Tomás Compactly supportedness guarantee that we can always choose this open $\Omega$, such that $f$ vanishes outside a compact supported set inside this $\Omega$, please see my edit, I made the choice of $\Omega$ more clear, thanks for bringing this up.

Comment: @Tomás Yes I used $\partial v/\partial n = 0$ on $\partial \Omega$, together with trace of $v$ is zero, there goes $\nabla v = 0$ on the boundary, then Friedrichs inequality on $\nabla v$ by summing up the estimate for each component.

Comment: I have made an update on this post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/430939/is-it-true-that-f-in-w-1-p-mathbbrn-then-gamma-star-f-in-w1-p-m Please verify if it is correct. Thank you